# Hide sheet from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

So let's say I have a workbook called `Workbook 1`, is it possible if I run a macro to hide **Sheet 1**, **Sheet 2**, **Sheet 3** from `Workbook 2`? The catch here is that so long the sheet names contain **Sheet**, it should be hidden. Thanks in advance for any input! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code should do what you want. Please try it. It will hide all sheets whose name starts with "Sheet" except that it will retain one if there is no sheet that doesn't qualify.

```
Sub HideSheets()

    Dim WbName As String
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer

    WbName = "Test.xlsx"                    ' specify the target

    On Error Resume Next
    Set Wb = Workbooks(WbName)
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        On Error GoTo 0
        With Wb
            If InStr(1, .ActiveSheet.Name, "Sheet", vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
                ' ensure that the ActiveSheet will not be hidden
                For i = 1 To (.Worksheets.Count - 1)
                    Set Ws = .Worksheets(i)
                    If InStr(1, Ws.Name, "Sheet", vbTextCompare) <> 1 Then Exit For
                Next i
                Ws.Activate
            End If

            For Each Ws In Wb.Worksheets
                If Not Ws Is .ActiveSheet Then
                    If InStr(1, Ws.Name, "Sheet", vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
                        Ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
                        ' replace with xlSheetVeryHidden to exclude the sheet
                        ' from the list of hidden worksheets accessible by the
                        ' user. VerHidden worksheets can only be made visible
                        ' from the VB Editor Project Explorer window or using code.
                    End If
                End If
            Next Ws
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "The workbook """ & WbName & """ must be open.", _
               vbInformation, "Failure notice"
    End If
End Sub
```